# When the graph of $y = f(x)$ is reflected in the line $y = x$, the number of invariant points is

Tags: functions, inverse, transformation, reflection, fixed-points

[image: The graph of the function is given in the image]

What are the invariants?

Would the invariant points be where the points of reflected graph and original intersect?

Comment: "Would the invariant points be where the points of reflected graph and original intersect?" -- Yes. And in fact you say say more than that: they have to lie on $y=x$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer They don't have to lie on the line $x=y$ if they are only defined as the intersection of the graph with its reflection. Points that are unmoved by the reflection must be on the line, but one part of the graph could very well intersect with a different part of the reflected graph.

Comment: So what is the rule for determining invariant points when there is a reflection in the y = x?  Do invariant points of the reflected function have to intersect the original function AND the line y = x?

Comment: @user7123308 To me, the natural interpretation would be the points that don’t move, i.e. the points on $\{y=x\}$. In contrast, if the reflected graph intersects the original somewhere else, what you have are two points that swap places, which I wouldn’t call invariant. But I suppose I can’t guarantee that the other interpretation is impossible.

Comment: also see [fixed point](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FixedPoint.html)

Comment: I second Milten's thinking... maybe "common points" instead should we wish to describe the points shared by the graph and its image.

Answer (score 0):

The invariant points are going to be the points that do not change when a function undergoes one or more transformations. Invariant points will also occur on the graph of a function when they lie on the line of reflection. Therefore, there are two invariant points, one is at $(-1, -1)$ and the other is at $(1.5, 1.5)$. Both of the these lie on the line of reflection of $y = x$.